# ZSH completion from script prompt (like BASH's read -e)

Tags: bash, zsh, bash-completion, zsh-completion

In a bash shell script you can prompt the user for input and enable readline completion for the user with the `-e` flag. (e.g. `read -e -p 'GET YOUR FILE: ' file` would allow a the user to use tab-completion to find the file.)

ZSH's completion is more advanced and extendable, so I hoped that I might be able to find a zsh builtin that allowed similar behavior.

Comment: Are you asking for something that works in `zsh` or in `bash`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better answer (I just recently started experimenting with `zsh`), but you can use `vared`.

```
$ vared -c line
```

Comment: Works great, the first line isn't needed though if you pass the `-c` flag.